# Reload partial with scripts

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to reload a section on with the following...

```
jQuery('#account_alert').replaceWith("<div id='account_alert'><div class='msg success'>" + data.message + "</div></div>");

jQuery('#subaccount_balances').load("edit #subaccount_balances");
```

The problem is `.load()` will not load the scripts from the webpage so
my accordions all expand and all the form links are broken...

Comment: The jQuery documentation says this is how it works: if the URL contains a selector expression, scripts are not executed.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I read the api and saw that, do you know of another way that this can be accomplished?

Comment: Can you change the server script so you don't need to use the `#subaccount_balances` selector?

Comment: I put the subaccount selector just for this, so yes it can be removed

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` doesn't execute scripts when there's a selector in the URL being loaded.

Change your `edit` server script so it takes a parameter named `section`. When this is given, it should only return that section of the the HTML instead of the whole page. Then you can do:

```
jQuery('#subaccount_balances').load("edit?section=subaccount_balances");
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear it is not necessary for the function of the webpage but if I load edit into #subaccount_balances it will reload the entire webpage into that selector, which is not what I am looking for... it would also do away with my replace alert... One option I thought of was perhaps making a literal separate page for the form and having render each time, is this a good solution?

Comment: I asked if you can change the `edit` script so you don't need to use the selector, you said you could.

Comment: I miss understood the question, I thought you were asking if the #subaccount_balances selector was necessary which it isnt... I can reload the edit page and it will lose the alert msg generated... but I just want to reload what is in the subaccount_balances selector or an inverse would be to reload everything but what is in the alert selector

Comment: I attempted your revision today and it doesnt seem to be working I am specifying the section and it is reloading but it is reloading the whole page inside the selector

Comment: Even though you revised the `edit` script so that it only sends the section you request?